# SugarCRM invoice add logic hook to display price detail

Tags: php, hook, sugarcrm, invoice

When creating an invoice with SugarCRM, I would like to add a line to the invoice header section displaying details of the total amount of the invoice (VAT included and VAT excluded) total amount. The two values can be calculated using the price keyed in in the invoice detail section. 
I am told to implement this functionality using the logic hook function of SugarCRM. Since I am new to SugarCRM, could you please advise ?

This is what I have done so far :

```
    <?php
      class AddLines {
      function update_amount(&$bean, $event, $arguments) 
      {
       //Query c_inv_fee_distribution table for detail_amount value of parent

       $bean->client_po = 'working';    
      } 
  }

  class PriceCalc {
    function taxdetail(&$bean, $event, $arguments)
    {
      $total_amt_excl = 0;
      $total_amt_incl = 0;
      $line_price = $number_units * $unit_price;

      $invoicelength = count($bean->invoice);

      for ($line_number=0; $line_number < $invoicelength); $line_number++)
      {
          if $VAT = true {
          $total_amt_excl += $line_price[line_number];
          $total_amt_incl += $line_price[line_number] * 1.14;    
          }else {
          $total_amt_excl += $line_price[line_number];
          $total_amt_incl += $line_price[line_number];
          }         
      }
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: I have two modules for the invoice, invoice header and invoice detail. I added a logic hook in the invoice detail part to calculate the two values, but I cannot make them appear in the invoice header which is basically a summary of the invoice.

Comment: Which version of Sugar CRM you're using? Is this hook to be applied to a custom module?

Comment: Hi, I'm using the Version 7.3.1, and yes it is to be applied to a custom module which is responsible for the invoice part.

Comment: Please refer to my post in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38370971/sugarcrm-invoice-add-logic-hook-to-calculate-line-price/38399865#38399865 and see if it helps you. It's about adding a custom field to Accounts module, but it's for a different version.