# SugarCRM invoice add logic hook to calculate line price

Tags: php, hook, sugarcrm, invoice

When creating an invoice with SugarCRM, in the invoice detail there's number of unit and unit price. I would like to populate the field line price automatically, which is simply the product of those two fields above. 
Here is what I added in the custom/modules/C_Inc_Invoice_Detail directory :

logic_hook.php

```
<?php

    $hook_version = 1;

    $hook_array = array();
    $hook_array['after_save'] = array();
    $hook_array['after_save'][] = array(
        1,
        'Auto Fill Line price',
        'custom/modules/C_Inv_Invoice_Detail/autofilllineprice.php',
        'AutoFillLinePrice',
        'autofilllineprice'
    );
    ?>
```

and the autofilllineprice.php :

```
<?php
    //prevents directly accessing this file from a web browser
    if
    (!defined('sugarEntry') ||!sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

    class AutoFillLinePrice {

    function autofilllineprice($bean, $event, $arguments){
    $line_price = $bean->unit_price * $bean->number_units;    
    }
    }
?>
```

Could you advise ?

Comment: Which version of Sugar CRM you're using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using the version 7.3.1.

Comment: Unfortunately, I use a different version. I've posted an answer detailing the steps involved in adding a custom field to Accounts module. Please see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This post does not answer this question directly, but it documents the steps involved in accomplishing a similar requirement. The **Accounts** module in SugarCE-6.5.22 has a field **Annual Revenue** and it's displayed in the **DetailView** as shown below.

[image: Accounts Module - DetailView]

The following are the steps involved in adding a new field that displays the value of this field converted to some other currency.

1. The first step is to create a non-db field that will hold the value of this new currency. For this, we need to create two files, one that defines the field("custom_fields.php") and the other that defines a language specific dispplay value for this field("en_us_custom_fields.php"). These two files are to be created in the below mentioned location. Please create the required directory structure if not present already.

**custom\Extension\modules\Accounts\Ext\Vardefs\custom_fields.php**

```
<?php

    if (!defined('sugarEntry') ||!sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

    $dictionary['Account']['fields']['annual_revenue_inr'] = array(
                'name' => 'annual_revenue_inr',
                'vname' => 'LBL_ANNUAL_REVENUE_INR',
                'label'=>'LBL_ANNUAL_REVENUE_INR',
                'type' => 'name',
                'module' => 'Accounts',
                'source' => 'non-db',
                'studio' => array('detailview'=>true),
                'default_value' => '',
                'help' => 'Annual Revenue(INR)',
                'comment' => 'Annual Revenue(INR)',
                'reportable' => true,
                'audited' => false,
                'duplicate_merge' => false,
                'importable' => 'true',         
            );

?>
```

**custom\Extension\modules\Accounts\Ext\Language\en_us_custom_fields.php**

```
<?php

    if (!defined('sugarEntry') ||!sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

    $mod_strings['LBL_ANNUAL_REVENUE_INR'] = 'Annual Revenue(INR)';

?>
```

After adding these two files, we need to run **Admin-->Repair-->Quick Repair and Rebuild**.  After it's complete, if we open **Admin-->Studio** and expand **Accounts-->Layouts-->DetailView**, we should see our newly created field available there. We can drag and drop it inside the layout wherever we want it to appear and click **Save & Deploy**.

[image: Studio - Accounts Module DetailView Layout]

Now, this new field should be visible in the detail view of the account.

2. The next task is to populate the value for this new currency. This can be achieved using logic hooks provided by SugarCRM. We need to compute the value for this field everytime after an account data is retrieved from database. The **after_retrieve** event can be used for this.  First, let's create a php file("annual_revenue_hook.php") with code that computes the value of this new currency field in the following location.

**custom\Extension\modules\Accounts\Ext\hooks\annual_revenue_hook.php**

```
<?php

    if (!defined('sugarEntry') ||!sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

    class AnnualRevenue {

        function computeAnnualRevenueINR($bean, $event, $arguments){
            $bean->annual_revenue_inr = $bean->annual_revenue * 100; 
        }

    }

?>
```

To register the above hook, we need to edit the logic_hooks.php file of the module and add the following lines:

**custom\modules\Accounts\logic_hooks.php**

```
//Create a new array that holds after_retrieve event hooks if not present already
$hook_array['after_retrieve'] = Array(); 

//Register our annual revenue hook for computing new currency value
$hook_array['after_retrieve'][]= Array(1, 'Compute Annual Revenue in INR', 'custom/Extension/modules/Accounts/Ext/hooks/annual_revenue_hook.php','AnnualRevenue', 'computeAnnualRevenueINR');
```

After completing these steps, we should see the value of the new currency populated in the detail view as shown below:

[image: New Field added to DetailView of Accounts]

It's also possible to get data from associated modules. For example, let's say we need to calculate the sum of all **Opportunities** associated with this **Account** and add to our new field. The following are the steps to accomplish it:

1. The first step is to get the relationship information between the modules, in this case between **Accounts** and **Opportunities**. We need to open the file **modules\Accounts\vardefs.php** and search for **Opportunities**. It should give us the following information.

   ```
   'opportunities' =>
   array (
   'name' => 'opportunities',
   'type' => 'link',
   'relationship' => 'accounts_opportunities',
   'module'=>'Opportunities',
   'bean_name'=>'Opportunity',
   'source'=>'non-db',
       'vname'=>'LBL_OPPORTUNITY',
   ),
   ```

Then, we can open **Admin-->Studio**, expand **Accounts-->Relationships** and find the type of relationship as shown below:

[image: Relationship between Accounts and Opportunities]

Now that we have identified the relationship information, we can edit our existing hook as shown below:

**custom\Extension\modules\Accounts\Ext\hooks\annual_revenue_hook.php**

```
<?php

    if (!defined('sugarEntry') ||!sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

    class AnnualRevenue {

        function computeAnnualRevenueINR($bean, $event, $arguments){
            $bean->annual_revenue_inr = $bean->annual_revenue * 100;
            $bean->load_relationship('opportunities');
            $opportunities = $bean->opportunities->getBeans();
            //Every account has multiple opportunities i.e array of Opportunity
            foreach($opportunities as $opportunity){
                $bean->annual_revenue_inr = $bean->annual_revenue_inr + $opportunity->amount;
            }
        }

    }
?>
```

The above code should now multiply annual_revenue by 100 and also sum up all the associated **Opportunities** with it to calculate the value of annual_revenue_inr.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It worked perfectly for my line price calculation ! 
But now I have another question, when doing a calculation, do you know how to get access to data which is from another module ? I am working with two modules now, invoice header and invoice detail, and I would like to use a price in the invoice detail to calculate a new price, and then show this new price in the invoice header. Do you know how should I proceed ?

Comment: It's possible to get data from another module if there's a link between the modules. I've updated my answer with sample code to get data from **Opportunities** module within a hook in **Accounts** module. Please see if it helps you.

Comment: It was a great help thank you very much ! 
Now it calculates the value and populate the field when I create a new invoice detail. But is there a way to actually save the calculated fields into the database ? Because now that happens is that once the invoice detail is created, I can see the field populated with the calculation, but i have to edit and save the detail again to save the values into the database..

Comment: If you need to save these values in database, create **db fields** instead of **non-db fields** and use a `before_save` event hook to calculate the values. It should be persisted in database if you do so. Please refer to the SugarCRM documentation corresponding to your version if you face any issues.

Comment: Hi again, thank you very much for your help it worked !I tried to use the same method with the Users module